# Which is probability that the student enter at least one university?

Tags: probability

A student give exams to 3 universities. The chance to enter the first is: 80%, to the second is 70% and in the third 60%.

> Which is probability that the student enter at least one university?

Comment: $1-(1-0.8)\cdot(1-0.7)\cdot(1-0.6)$

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: You show me yours and I'll show you mine.

Comment: I don't understand why you make difference:  **1-(1-80%)** what it means?

Comment: You've already posted over $70$ questions here, you should know better than that to show your efforts in attempting to answer the question on your own before asking others to make that effort for you.

Comment: The probability of entering "at least one" is 1 minus the probability of NOT entering any.  The probability of NOT  entering A is 1- .8= .2.  The probability of NOT entering B is 1- .7= .3.  The probability of NOT entering C is 1- .6= .4.  The probability of not getting into any of the colleges is (1- .8)(1- .7)(1- .6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability he doesn't get into any is (1-.8)(1-.7)(1-.6) = .2*.3*.4 = 3/125

The probability you're looking for is the compliment of the above probability. So the probability he gets into at least 1 university is 1- 3/125= 122/125.

Comment: But whi is $1-.8$ and not $2-.8$  what means this 1?

Comment: Think of it as 100% - 80% since each probability is independent of the others.